# Selenium cannot find item list input

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello I'm learning selenium and I've met first problem. I was searching for it very long and tested a lot of solutions and none of them worked for me.

This is how looks button which I want to click (I want to click Events button in navbar)

```
<div id="navbar-items" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#events">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#venues">Venues</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#bookings">Bookings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#monitor">Monitor</a></li>
                    <li><a href="admin">Administration</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

And here is my java code:

```
public class SeleniumTest {

@Test
public void startWebDriver() throws InterruptedException{

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("http://localhost:8080/ticket-monster/");

    Assert.assertTrue("title should start differently",              
            driver.getTitle().startsWith("Ticket Monster"));

    Thread.sleep(7000);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='navbar-items'][2]")).click();

    //*[@id="navbar-items"]/ul/li[2]/a

// I also was trying this and nothing clicked events button
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class='nav navbar-nav'])2]")).click();
//driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul > li:nth-child(2)")).click();
}
}
```

Here is website on which on I am practising it may be helpful.
http://ticketmonster-jdf.rhcloud.com/

I will be very thankful for every help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code and let me know.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("example.com");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='navbar-items']/ul/li[2]/a")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='navbar-items']/ul/li[2]/a")).click();
```

And Xpath is the slowest, so xpath is used when we don't have any option. Fortunately the xpath is taking the id so here it is all good.

Comment: Now it is working, thank you so much for fast and working answer :) I was trying to do this for about 1.5hour.

Comment: No problem. Enjoy.. But remember to use xpath when you don't have any option.  Happy Learning. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("http://ticketmonster-jdf.rhcloud.com/");
String eventXpath = "html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a";

WebElement eventElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))
                    .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(eventXpath)));        

eventElement.click();
```

Even in an alternate way you can achieve using the link text locator with the below code.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("http://ticketmonster-jdf.rhcloud.com/");

String linkText = "Events";

WebElement eventElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))
        .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText(linkText)));        

eventElement.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElemnt(By.xpath("//div[@id='navbar-items']/ul/li/a[contains(text(),'YOUR LISTED TEXT')]")).click()
```

This might help you